# Optimal Approaches to AWS Glue ETL Job Monitoring with CloudWatch Metrics

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I've a glue ETL job which takes files from one folder in S3 and moves them to another S3 folder with partitioning the data by date.
I'm looking for a way to monitor the glue job using the cloudwatch metrics and alarms, the monitoring should include basic notifications for job start, end, failure, some custom business notification, but there seems to be several related issues:

1. if a job is executed in less than 30 sec, no metrics will be provided,  in case of a quick failure there's no notification.
   https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/glue-job-metrics-cloudwatch
2. from other sources i understand that the metrics provided by glue itself not always reliable
3. as i have a single glue job at the moment, i'm not sure that going with an intresting approach mentioned in https://medium.com/@ettefette/metrics-for-aws-glue-jobs-as-you-know-them-from-lambda-functions-e5e1873c615c will help me, as it involves additional resources

My idea was simple, I've added custom metrics to the glue script and it worked. i'm able to see the metrics in Cloudwatch and create a dashboard.

My questions are:

1. is it a good practice to add custom metrics to glue python script?
2. is there a better solution to implement state execution monitoring for glue job?

Your input is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex